# Visual Studio 2015 - brackets not automatically formatting when pressing shift + enter

Tags: visual-studio, ide, visual-studio-2015

Normally, to create a new bracket block I would type:

"{" then enter

This produces:

```
{

}
```

however, (I have seen this on two different machines so far, it might be the default setting) if like me, you like to keep shift held down, or accidentally keep it down and instead press shift + enter, it creates a new line underneath.

```
{ }
//current cursor position
```

Leaving the un-formatted brackets behind!

This is really annoying as I nearly always do this, and have to fiddle around for a little second to get the brackets back to where I want them. What can I do to change the behavior of shift + enter?

Comment: The very same problem here. Drives me mad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We stumbled on this thread and it felt like we could make a nice improvement here to Shift+Enter (SmartBreakLine).

So, in cases where a block was opened `{ }` and if `shift` was held down intentionally or unintentionally, we now do this:

```
{
    |
}
```

instead of

```
{ }
|
```

this way people who are used to using shift+enter to complete the line (in C#, it adds a semicolon to the end of line if needed, formats the line, adds a new line after current line) do not have to lose those functionalities by remapping the shortcut to BreakLine.

See: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/pull/5790

this should make it in the next update of Vs2015 and we hope you like it.

Comment: update: [This build](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-update1-vs.aspx) has the fix :)

Answer (score 12):

Go to **Options > Environment > Keyboard**

- Search for **Edit.SmartBreakLine** and remove the assigned shortcut (Shift + Enter)
- Search for **Edit.BreakLine**, click on "Press shortcut keys:" textbox, press Shift + Enter and click Assign

If it doesn't work try restarting Visual Studio.

**Update: This issue is fixed in Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 - SmartBreakLine works as expected.**

Comment: Ah, so the shift key was sticky while I hit return! That explains. It's a pity to remove this shortcut, but it certainly clears the nuisance with brackets.

Comment: @Timo I don't think it is being removed, like the answer by balajikris says, the behavior in the next version of VS will be changed so that it recognizes this situation ^. You don't have to remove it then.

Comment: @SamWalls I mean with this particular answer, we are removing the SmartBreakLine shortcut, including where it *is* desired.

Answer (score 0):

It works well in my VS 2015. Try resetting all the settings.

**Tools > Import and Export Settings > Reset all settings > Next > Visual C#**

You can reset for all other languages similar like this.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Doesn't work. You are probably not trying to reproduce it right.