# How to disable semi-colon insertion when using object initializers in Visual Studio 2015 C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I just started using Visual Studio 2015 (have been using Visual Studio for 10+ years), and the new 'helpful' syntax insertion has been driving me crazy. I usually write object initializers on their own line like so:

```
var myCar = new CarInfo()
{
    Make = "Make",
    Model = "Model",
    Year = 2015
};
```

However, when I try to type this, a ; is inserted when I hit shift+enter after this line

```
 var myCar = new CarInfo()
```

resulting in a bunch of compiler errors and Intellisense sluggishness as it tries to figure out what I meant by:

```
var myCar = new CarInfo();
{
    Make = "Make",
    Model = "Model",
    Year = 2015
};
```

Does anyone know how to turn this off? I do not have any extensions installed that modify the code editor.

Comment: Not an answer to the question, but how about using the syntax `new CarInfo { ... };` instead, i.e. skip the unnecessary parentheses. Since you're not sending in any arguments to the constructor, they can be skipped.

See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32259287/visual-studio-2015-brackets-not-automatically-formatting-when-pressing-shift

Answer (score 1):

Instead of just an enter you should press the <kbd>{</kbd> key and then press enter. By using this order, the code will be indented normally.

Comment: I could almost accept this as an answer, except my issue is retraining my brain to stop typing the way it has for years and the slowdown that occurs from having to think about it. I really just want  a solution that allows for only what I type to appear in the editor.

Comment: I've checked the intellisense options but I don't think it is possible without a plugin.

Comment: I checked them before posting too, including the registry to see if there are hidden options like for the All Caps menus (not that I mind those personally).